# Storing objects in an array in javascript is storing the function

Tags: javascript

I have a custom object called pipe

```
function pipe()
{
    this.x = 800;
    this.width = 50;
    this.y = 450;
}
```

When I try storing pipes in an array its not storing the object, but the function.

```
function loop()
{
    var flappy = new player();
    for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        var p = new pipe();
        p.x = (1 + i) * 266;
        pipes.push(pipe);
    }
    interval = window.setInterval(function() { updateLogic(flappy) } , 20);
}
```

If I try accessing a property of a pipe in pipes it says undefined.

```
var pipe = pipes[0];
console.log(pipe.x);
```

Comment: `pipe` will return function expression(body). Have you defined `var pipes = []` anywhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `pipes.push(pipe)` instead of `pipes.push(p)`.

Comment: This would be the culprit. Thank you